# Got into a car accident, do I need a police report?

Tags: united-states, california, vehicle, accident

I got into a car accident today. There are no injuries involved. Do I need to file a police report? I live in California. One police station tells me that I don’t need to file a report, another tells me that I do. I’m confused.

Comment: What's your insurance company say?

Comment: Can you give some specifics on the police accident?  Are you going to involve insurance?  Are you at fault or was the other driver?

Comment: @hszmv I would say that it was both our fault, but aren’t we supposed to blame each other or something? That’s based off of what I read online.

Comment: @mkennedy oh right. I should have called them.

Comment: @AuroraAfable:  Legal fault in these situations usually goes down to who had right of way OR who rear ended who (person who hits the rear end of another car is very likely at fault in a two car collision).  Even if one person was not paying attention, it does not necessarily make them at fault because a reasonable vehicle operator is not looking to be hit in an intersection or while staying in the same lane on a high way.  A better rephrase would be could you provide details into what happened and who hit whom?

Comment: @mkennedy they said that we didn't need a police report. Filing a claim is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must file a report if there was any injury, or property damage over $1,000. [Here](https://www.dmv.ca.gov/web/eng_pdf/sr1.pdf) is the form. The officers giving advice may have different views of the level of property damage.